# What can happen to my Partial Psychic from using his power?

Tags: stars-without-number

I've just started playing in a *Stars Without Number* (Revised Edition) campaign.  My character has a Technician background, and Adventurer class (Partial Expert, Partial Psychic), with foci of Starfarer and Tinker.  He has Telekinesis at Level 0, but no Psychic Training.

I saw something during character creation about things happening to "untrained psychics" who use their power.  What do I need to watch out for or expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untrained NPC psychics use the Torching rules in the Psionics chapter every time they use their powers. As someone with the Psychic class, however, you've received some training somehow, or else you're the one-in-a-million natural prodigy who figures it out without help. The Psychic Training focus is just an additional perk indicating extra competence in your field.